# Small frontal camera preview (not fullscreen)?

Tags: android, camera, preview

is there a way to have a small camera preview inside a view? Not the classic fullscreen preview, I mean.

My idea is to create an app that allows the user to take pics of himself with the frontal camera, when it's **dark**.

Basically, I thought to put a small preview of the camera on the corner of the screen and setting the remaining part to full brightness  (to use it like a "self flash").

Well, I don't have problems actually to set a view to a full brightness value, but I don't have any idea how to resize the frontal camera preview.

I hope you understood my intention...

Any help would appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe this idea will hold water, because the brightness of the screen may not be enough. But the technical question you ask is not very hard: you can put the ViewSurface for your preview in the main activity's xml with any size you choose (you can use the usual WISIWYG layout editor in ADS or AndroidStudio).